# Adaptive Payments (Chained Payments) - Secondary Receiver pay the fee

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

When we try to set the secondary receiver pay the fee in chained payments, and when there are more than two secondary receivers, we get the below error.

> Error! 580023 The fee payer SECONDARYONLY must have exactly 2
>   receivers PLATFORM Error Application Failure
>   2016-03-18T23:59:12.805-07:00 eee07aae3f51c 20420247

We would like to know how many secondary receivers are allowed in a chained payment when we set the secondary receivers to pay the fees (SECONDARYONLY)

Answer (score 0):

For Chained Payment, you can't have the secondary receiver to pay for the fees if the receiver is more than 2 (primary + secondary). If you have more than 2 receivers, you can't set SECONDARYONLY to pay the fees. Refer [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).